# No Response from MapQuest addRoute Method

Tags: mapquest

I'm using MapQuest on a web page to show all store locations in the area.  Everything works fine--the map loads and displays the stores correct--but when I make a call to the routing api, I never get a response.  It doesn't throw an error, and neither the *success* nor *error* methods get called.  Is it swallowing an exception somewhere?

Here is my code...

```
MQA.withModule('new-route', function () {
    map.addRoute({
        request: { locations: [fromAddress, toAddress] },

        // enable dragging through the route display options
        display: { draggable: true, draggablepoi: false },
        success: function displayNarrative(data) {
            console.log("Success -- for now...");
        },
        error: function handleError(data) {
            console.log("Error!");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried wrapping the whole thing in a try...catch and it never catches anything.

My *fromAddress* and *toAddress* arguments are both valid addresses.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the route request being made in the Network tab? Is there a successful response there?

Be aware that the MapQuest JavaScript api is deprecated and will be sunset in about 18 months. I recommend moving to the MapQuest plugins for Leaflet or any of the other supported sdks mentioned in [this blog post](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2016/06/03/product-launch-reinvent-your-maps-with-our-mobile-sdks-for-ios-and-android/).

Comment: Yes, I did check.  Nothing.  No outgoing requests.

Comment: Are there any errors or anything else i the console?